# #1227 - Access denied; you need the CREATE USER privilege for this operation

Tags: php, mysql

Note:I uses 000webhost.com's phpmyadmin
My coding is

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
        WITH GRANT OPTION;
 CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
        WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And my error is

> ## 1227 - Access denied; you need the CREATE USER privilege for this operation

Comment: Do you have a question?  The error message seems quite clear.  You need to talk to your DBA.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code itself, your database account just does not have the privileges to create a new user. Either you add that permission flag to "monty" or contact the database administrator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make sure you have the correct db configuraion:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'mysq--.000webhost.com');
```